# What's the best way to validate multiple JSON field dependencies?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to create a schema that will validate multiple fields with dependencies so that I can use the validation to show or hide certain fields in a form generator. Ideally it would work something like this:

`{ firstName: "Charles" } // hiddenField is valid`

`{ firstName: "Bob" } // hiddenField is invalid`

`{ cityOfBirth: "Boston" } // hiddenField2 is valid`

`{ cityOfBirth: "Anything" } // hiddenField2 is invalid`

`{ firstName: "Charles", cityOfBirth: "Boston" } // hiddenField & hiddenField2 are valid`

`{ firstName: "Charles", cityOfBirth: "Anything" } // hiddenField is valid & hiddenField2 is invalid`

```js
{
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      firstName: {
        type: "string"
      },
      countryOfBirth: {
        type: "string",
        enum: ["England", "Italy"]
      },
      cityOfBirth: {
        type: "string"
      },
      hiddenField: {
        type: "string"
      },
      hiddenField2: {
        type: "string"
      }
    },
    dependentSchemas: {
      hiddenField: {
        properties: {
          firstName: {
            type: "string",
            const: "Charles"
          }
        }
      },
      hiddenField2: {
        properties: {
          cityOfBirth: {
            type: "string",
            const: "Boston"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a classic question that is served by using the `if`, `then`, `else` keywords. If you search for questions asked in just the last few weeks you will find similar usecases.

Comment: @Ether do you mean using `if`, `then`, `else`, with the `required` keyword? I've done that before but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for..

Comment: correct. `"if":{"required":["propertyname"]}, ... ` will check for the existence of a property; if you want to check the exact value of a property as well, then you can add `"const":"<value>"` to the conditional.